# Is a class immutable if its readonly fields are not immutable?

Tags: c#, immutability

If I have a C# class with only readonly fields, but the fields' types are NOT immutable, is the class considered immutable?

Is this class immutable?

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly int[] _blah;

    public Foo(int[] blah)
    {
        _blah = blah;
    }

    public int[] Blah { get { return _blah; } }
}
```

_blah is not immutable, since I can change the members of the array, though the array member variable can never change.

So, is a class immutable if its fields are all readonly, or is a class immutable only if its fields are not only readonly, but also immutable themselves?

Comment: You should read this blog post on [kinds of immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) and clarify the question with what kind you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will really depend on who you ask or what you mean. Some might say that the class itself is immutable because its direct members are immutable. Some might say that the class and all its members (and their properties, etc) -- basically, the entire object graph -- must be immutable in order to be considered immutable.

- private field arrays marked as readonly are immutable, but that doesn't mean you can't replace the indexes with different values. A way to solve this is to return a copy of the array or an enumeration of the array
- The objects of the array may or may not be immutable. Whether you make them immutable or you return clones of the them or whatever, that's really up to you.

In your situation, the objects are integers (which are immutable), but your array itself isn't (again, depending what you define as immutable). If all you want to guarantee is the private field can't be altered and don't care about the indexes, then you're fine. But, if you want the indexes to be locked in then you need to expose your array in another way.

---

Also, a nice collection to look into is the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. It is a collection that holds a reference to the original collection (it wraps it), so that the indexes can't be changed.

---

Also, point in case... already you have varying answers to the degree of what "immutable" actually means.

Comment: The objects here are `int`s, so they are immutable, there is no `Blah` type in the code in the question.

Comment: Ah, I just saw `Blah` colorcoded and answered fast. But, the point still stands... "immutable" varies in definition based on who you ask. I'm going to update my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of this class are not immutable, because you can mutate their contents. E.g. `foo.Blah[0] = 42;`. But if you changed the `Blah` property to `IEnumerable<int>` or [`IReadOnlyList<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx), the instances would be considered immutable.

Comment: Isn't calling the class immutable a bit misleading? Its the instance of the class that is immutable

Comment: @terjetyl Right, I'm not sure it's such important distinction here, but I fixed it in my answer anyway.

Comment: An immutable class may legitimately encapsulate the state of a  mutable-type object, but only if one can be certain that no reference to that object will ever be exposed to code which might try to mutate it.  Merely casting an `int[]` to `IEnumerable<int>` won't prevent outside code from casting it back.  The `int[]` must be wrapped in something like `ReadOnlyCollection<int>` before exposure to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

This class is not immutable since it can be inherited and have other things added it.

Comment: Subclasses still won't be able to access private fields.

Comment: You could still make the subclasses sealed to make it immutable.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: You can't guarantee that any subclass will live up to that promise with its own fields, though.  "This class is immutable when it's treated as an A" is a really weak promise.

Comment: @cHao Actually, it's not such a weak promise, since the class doesn't have any `virtual` methods (ignoring the ones inherited from `object`). That means that if you treat the derived class as `Foo`, it will be immutable (assuming `Foo` itself can be considered immutable).

Comment: @svick: Yeah, but if you treat it as anything else, it may well not be.  That makes the type effectively useless for most of the situations where we'd find immutable types desirable.  Immutability is a promise that "i will never change", and a class that allows inheritance can't really make that promise.

Comment: @cHao That doesn't really make sense, this class presents a contract of a single property `Blah` and promises that that property will will always reference the same array.  This class never breaks its promise of not changing the array reference.  If any sub-classes introduce mutable properties, those classes have their own contracts, which don't effect this one.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: If it wants to say that `Blah` is immutable, let it go right ahead.  But it can not claim to be immutable itself.  Immutability is a much stronger promise than "these fields won't change"; it's more like "none of these objects' fields and none of these objects' fields' fields, etc, will change -- ever" (barring stupid reflection voodoo).  Anything that makes a weaker promise than that is not immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I think its immutable if it follows three principals:

- Make the fields private readonly.
- Provide a public property get accesor.
- If the class is not longer needed to be inherited, make it sealed.

These are not hard and fast rules with a strict definition of immutable. They are just guidelines.